# pros and cons between os.path.exists vs os.path.isdir

Tags: python, directory, os.path

I'm checking to see if a directory exists, but I noticed I'm using `os.path.exists` instead of `os.path.isdir`.  Both work just fine, but I'm curious as to what the advantages are for using `isdir` instead of `exists`.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

[`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) will also return `True` if there's a regular file with that name.

[`os.path.isdir`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) will only return `True` if that path exists and is a directory, or a symbolic link to a directory.

Comment: `os.path.isdir` is returning true for me on a symlink.

Comment: I am getting `os.path.isdir('.ipynb_checkpoints')` returning true

Comment: In Python 2.7 os.path.isdir returns true for symlinks to directories and false for symlinks to files (as expected).  However this can cause issues with os.rmdir because it will fail on a symlink even if it is a symlink to a directory.

Answer (score 6):

Just like it sounds like: if the path exists, but is a file and not a directory, `isdir` will return `False`. Meanwhile, `exists` will return `True` in both cases.

Answer (score 4):

**os.path.isdir()** checks if the path exists and is a directory and returns TRUE for the case.

Similarly, **os.path.isfile()** checks if the path exists and is a file and returns TRUE for the case.

And, **os.path.exists()**  checks if the path exists and doesn’t care if the path points to a file or a directory and returns TRUE in either of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, it is the same.

But, path can exist physically whereas `path.exists()` returns False. This is the case if os.stat() returns False for this file.

If path exists physically, then `path.isdir()` will always return True. This does not depend on platform.

Comment: Not clear what that last paragraph means. If a directory exists physically on a remote server, but I have no network connection where I'm running the script, then surely `isdir()` can't know whether the directory exists.

Comment: If you are checking if a directory exists on a UNC path, os.path.exists can return false when it actually exists (even with the connection working), but os.path.isdir will return the correct value.  For a file in the simlar UNC path case you should also use os.path.isfile instead of os.path.exists for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

> os.path.exists(path)
>   Returns True if path refers to an existing path. An existing path can
>   be regular files
>   (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types#Regular_file), but also
>   special files (e.g. a directory). So in essence this function returns
>   true if the path provided exists in the filesystem in whatever form
>   (notwithstanding a few exceptions such as broken symlinks).
>
> os.path.isdir(path)
>   in turn will only return true when the path points to a directory

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question, who is asking for differences between the two commands. You have only detailed one.