# Python os.path.exists returns false on windows 10 and true on windows 7 for the same network path

Tags: python, windows, macos

I tried to search a lot on the forums but just couldn't find the right answer.

One of my python scripts, which runs on a windows machine looks for the existence of a network path as the first thing.

```
myPath = "Y:\\Windows\\Builds\\"
if not os.path.exists(myPath):
    print("This one can't be reached : "+myPath)
```

This works perfectly fine from a windows 7 machine (The output is true). But running the same on a windows 10 machine, results in false. All three machines, the windows 7 one, windows 10 one and Y: (a mac) are on the same local network.

Y: is a mapped drive. I have also tried to repeat with the IP instead of the mapped drive name, without luck. I have checked the paths are correct knowing the command is case sensitive.

Any help here will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try to stat the file? `os.stat(myPath)`.

Comment: Try `os.path.join(Windows,Builds)`

Comment: Mapped drives are created per logon session. If you have UAC enabled, then be aware that anything you do while elevated (i.e. "run as administrator")  is in a different logon session. So if you map a drive in Explorer, it won't be available in an elevated command prompt; you'll have to remap it using `net use [A-Z]: [\\computername\sharename]`.

Comment: @Dunes, if I try os.stat, it returns this
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Y:\\Windows\\Builds\\'

Comment: @Ravichandra, I tries he os.path.join, but with the same response

Comment: @eryksun, I have mounted the drives as the same user. And I am running the script as the same user. So it should be the same logon session. Just to avoid the confusion, I also tried the full path with the IP of the machine. That also didn't work

Comment: OK, it's not working for other reasons. But just FYI, under UAC an administrator is logged on with a restricted token, which is not the same logon session as the unrestricted token used by elevated processes.

Comment: Just for giggles, navigate in `cmd` to the target directory and type `python -c 'import os; print os.getcwd()'` in both Windows 7 and 10.

Answer (score 2):

You may try `os.path.join()` to join paths:

```
path = os.path.join("Y:","windows","Build")
```

This will create a path string with regard to OS - for Windows7 `windows\\Build` and for Linux `windows/Build`.

use [`os.path.isdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) Return True if path is an existing directory.

Comment: I tries he os.path.join, but with the same response. I am trying to access the shared files on a mac from a windows 10 machine via the python script.

Comment: try `os.path.isdir()`

Comment: So os.path.isdir returns 'True' and os.path.exists returns 'False. What could be the cause?

I can access the path manually via windows explorer.

Comment: @RohitSinghal Is `os.path.isdir()` working ?? IFF because `path.isdir()` is platform independent.  check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077424/python-os-path-exists-vs-os-path-isdir   check `octoblack` answer

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the post. However, I still couldn't fix my problem. I do understand the platform independent thing of 'isdir'. But, if 'exists' returns false, my shutil.copy2 from that path fails as well. Could you point me to a platform independent copy command?

Comment: try `os.system(cp source_path destination_path)`. I am not sure weather will it work or Not in your case !!

Comment: @rohitSinghal Try to reach source path from cmd prompt and use same.

Comment: @ravicandra I could get it working using the combination of os.path.isdir() and the cp command. please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @RohitSinghal ok Thank you !!

Comment: Another option is to build your path like so: \\\\servername\\folder\\folder\\file.txt - Essentially you have to escape the slashes

Answer (score 1):

If it is a network share you have to use the full path e.g.:

```
from pathlib import Path

myPath = Path('//server/sharename/Windows/Builds/')
if not os.path.exists(myPath):
    print("This one can't be reached : " + myPath)
```